# Angular 5: Nested child routes in same router-outlet (arbitrary level)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

Initially i wanted to add breadcrumbs. A flat route-hierarchy seemed not to fit this task very well. The app consist of a tab structure and all the other content will be loaded in one router-outlet.

Using child's, i was able to dig one level down:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'StartPage',
      role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
    },
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      component: StartComponent // StartPage-Component
    },
      {
        path: 'overview/cars',
        component: OverviewCarsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'CarsOverview',
          role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
        }
      }
    ]
  } ...
```

But after that, nothing wanted to work. For example, i've tried:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'StartPage',
      role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
    },
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      component: StartComponent // StartPage-Component
    },
      {
        path: 'overview/cars',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'CarsOverview',
          role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
        }, 
        children: [
                 {
                  path: 'overview/cars',
                  component: OverviewCarsComponent
                 },
                 {
                  path: 'overview/cars/add',
                  component: AddCarsComponent
                  canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
                  data: {
                    title: 'AddCars',
                    role: [UserRole.Employee]
                  }
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  } ...
```

I didn't find some best practice to handle this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try to change is under child routes. The path was already defined on the parent level, the base path that is - overview/cars - so you can truncate that from the child routes and do it like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'StartPage',
      role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
    },
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      component: StartComponent // StartPage-Component
    },
      {
        path: 'overview/cars',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        data: {
          title: 'CarsOverview',
          role: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Employee]
        }, 
        children: [
                 {
                  path: '',
                  component: OverviewCarsComponent
                 },
                 {
                  path: 'add',
                  component: AddCarsComponent
                  canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
                  data: {
                    title: 'AddCars',
                    role: [UserRole.Employee]
                  }
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  } ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Marko :) This structure itself seems to solve my problem, but generated a new one, which i already witnessed in upper level: (I think its because of the ''-path in each child,) The breadcrumbs are doubled. If there is no quick fix, i will work around this in the breadcrumbcomponent itself.